# How to subtract row value from same column with previous year in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have input data like this, with year name as a column, I want to subtract rating of past year from the present year with a new column as rating diff.

```
year,movie_name,language,rating  
2019,akash,english,10   
2019,antony,kannada,9   
2020,akash,english,10   
2020,antony,kannada,8
```

My result dataframe: which I want

```
year,movie_name,language,rating,rating_diff  
2019,akash,english,10,-  
2019,antony,kannada,9,-  
2020,akash,english,10,0        
2020,antony,kannada,8,-1
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So, what have you done?

Comment: I am using window function to partition by year and order by language,movie_name and then using lag to substract! but it is not giving result what i wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to compare the last year, the `year` should be the order by column. But also want to keep the `movie_name` and `language`, they should be the partition by column.

Compare the rating on the row with the latest year, the `lag` function is used when the order of the `date` is ascending.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('movie_name', 'language').orderBy('year')

df.withColumn('lead', f.lag('rating', 1).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('rating_diff', f.when(f.col('lead').isNotNull(), f.col('rating') - f.col('lead')).otherwise(f.lit(None))) \
  .show(10, False)

+----+----------+--------+------+----+-----------+
|year|movie_name|language|rating|lead|rating_diff|
+----+----------+--------+------+----+-----------+
|2019|antony    |kannada |9     |null|null       |
|2020|antony    |kannada |8     |9   |-1         |
|2019|akash     |english |10    |null|null       |
|2020|akash     |english |10    |10  |0          |
+----+----------+--------+------+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Lamannus, I had confusion with partitionby and orderby and I did otherway so I was not getting answer.